# Why we have to delete edmx and recreate it anew on the server, every change we make?

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, edmx, ado.net-entity-data-model

We make some `WCF` service that uses `Entity Framework` (`edmx` file). Every time we make a change (even not related to the framework / DB), we have to delete the `edmx` and recreate it and build the solution on the server itself, otherwise it cannot interact with the SQL Server.

Why, and how to solve it ?

Comment: That is not normal behavior, but you haven't really given enough info, like why you need to do this, what errors are you getting if you don't, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we also copied the `WhatEver.dll.config` that contained the connection string (which was different between the development PC and the server).

We now simply fix the connection string if we overrun the file `WhatEver.dll.config`...